# c# cannot convert from string to char

Tags: c#

I am trying to write some code to display any symbols present in a password the user gives you. I am quite new and am trying to do use `isSymbol` but I am stuck. it says cannot convert from string to char

```
using System;

namespace booleanprok
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a made up password:");
            string madeUppw = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(char.IsSymbol(madeUppw));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A string consists of 0 to many individual characters. You can't just convert a string (say `"hello"`) to a character. However the string class implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can `foreach` over a string as if it was a collection of `char`

Comment: `char` is a single character, `string` is a collection of characters. `madeUppw` is a `string`.

Comment: What is the intended result of the code?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("You entered the symbols: " + string.Join(", ", madeUppw.Where(char.IsSymbol)));`

Answer (score 1):

> *"I am trying to write some code to display any symbols present in a password the user gives you."*

Given the above statement, I see the following problems with the sample code given:

1. you're passing a `string` to the `IsSymbol()` method, which expects a `char`.
2. you're outputting the return value from the `IsSymbol()` method (which is a `bool`) instead of the characters themselves.
3. `IsSymbol()` does not return all characters that we typically consider symbols in a password (like `!`, `@`, `#`, etc). From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.issymbol?view=netframework-4.8): *"symbols are members of the following categories in UnicodeCategory: `MathSymbol`, `CurrencySymbol`, `ModifierSymbol`, and `OtherSymbol`."*

---

One way to solve these issues is to consider any character that's not alphabetic or numeric to be a "symbol", which we can do by using the Linq extension method `Where()` along with the `char.IsLetter()` and `char.IsDigit()` methods. Then we can output the characters to the console using `string.Join` on the results.

For example:

```
Console.Write("Enter a made up password: ");
string madeUpPwd = Console.ReadLine();

// Get the distinct characters that aren't Letters or Digits
IEnumerable<char> symbols = madeUpPwd
    .Where(c => !char.IsLetter(c) && !char.IsDigit(c))
    .Distinct();

// Output them to the console (separated by commas and wrapped in single quotes)
Console.WriteLine($"You entered the symbols: '{string.Join("', '", symbols)}'");
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

(Note that using `.Where(char.IsSymbol)` would have only return the `'$'` character)

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to char
Try this one

```
    bool res;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a made up password:");
    string madeUppw = Console.ReadLine();
    foreach(char s in madeUppw){
       res = Char.IsSymbol(s);//The char.issymbol takes characters as parameter 
    }
```

If you have a single character string, You can also try

```
string str = "A";
char character = char.Parse(str);
```

Or

```
string str = "A";
char character = str.ToCharArray()[0];
```

Comment: You don't need the `ToCharArray`, just `str[0]` will do as `string` has an index property.

Answer (score 0):

`char.IsSymbol` accepts a `char` argument, but you're passing a parameter of type `string`. If you're sure the input will only be one character in length, or if you just want the first character and disregard others, you can call `char.IsSymbol(madeUppw[0]);`

However, you can force reading a single character with `Console.ReadKey` and get the value with `KeyChar`:

```c#
char madeUppw = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
Console.WriteLine(char.IsSymbol(madeUppw));
```

Answer (score 0):

A string consists of 0 or more characters and for validating if any of the characters is an symbol, you need step through each of the characters in the string and validate them individually. You could do so using [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) and [`char.IsSymbol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.issymbol?view=netframework-4.8) as

```
string madeUppw = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(madeUppw.Any(x=>char.IsSymbol(x)));
```

`Enumerable.Any` verifies whether any of the elements in the sequence (in this a string),  exists or satisfies a condition (in this, condition is if any of the character is a Symbol).

The last line could further trimmed down as

```
Console.WriteLine(madeUppw.Any(char.IsSymbol));
```

If you need to print all the symbols in the string, you could use

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",madeUppw.Where(x=>char.IsSymbol(x))));
```